# ticks not showing as entered

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm working with highcharts' highstock library. I'm trying to populate monthly data on it but xAxis on navigator misses out some months. I need it to include ALL months. here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hassan_rehman/voazL4cn/).

I've tried the tick intervals:

```
navigator: {
  adaptToUpdatedData: false,
    xAxis: {
        minTickInterval: 30*24*3600*1000
    }
}
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable `tickPixelInterval` by setting it as null and then set `tickInterval` as 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/voazL4cn/3/