# navigator in highcharts not letting me decide the minimum range

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm using highcharts library with navigator to plot monthly data. I need the navigator to select ranges to a minimum of 1 month.

```
  navigator: {
    adaptToUpdatedData: false,
      xAxis: {
          minTickInterval: 30*24*3600*1000
      }
  },
```

However the maximum limit is somehow SET on navigator to something like 3.5 months. Any ideas on how to make it to 1 month?
here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hassan_rehman/voazL4cn/)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656231/ticks-not-showing-as-entered/27686982#27686982

Comment: No it isn't. The other question is about x-axis VALUES .. this question is about min-selectable-range on the navigator.

Answer (score 0):

It needs min, max, and minRange for xAxis i.e.

```
xAxis: {
  min: 1388534400000, 
  max: 1409529600000, 
  minRange: 30*24*3600*1000
}
```

here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hassan_rehman/sL2h015q/)